# fmincon fitted parameter values slightly outside of the bounds; is this within tolerance?

Tags: matlab, double, precision

I am using `fmincon` with lower bound `lb = [0, 0, 0]` and upper  bound `ub = [1, 1, 5]`.

For of the runs I have returned a first parameter value of `-2e-16` and other runs with second parameter values of order `-1e-11`.

Now, I think these values are actually equal to zero, within tolerance of floating point comparison. But I am rather disturbed that `fmincon` actually returned negative numbers.

Why is this happening? Is it because my bounds were not specified using integers?

Comment: What do you mean by " Is it because my bounds were not specified using integers?" – all of your bounds are integers. Intermediate iterations [can violate contraints](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/writing-constraints.html#br9p_ry). Hard to say what is truly going on without runnable code to see your function and how exactly you call `fmincon`. The value `-2e-16` is small relative to `1`, but depending on how your objective function is scaled it may be more important.

Comment: This is the final parameter value, so it is disturbing that it violates constraints. I thought all numbers as supplied to Matlab are by default double precision?

Comment: btw, with regards to how the objective function behaves around the point 0, I believe that it is zero.

Comment: Again, hard to say what is truly going on without runnable code to see your function and how exactly you call `fmincon`. If you have other constraints besides upper and lower bounds or if your objective function is sensitive (e.g., your three dimensions have wildly different gradients or nonlinearities), the solver may not be able to return values that meet all requirements in all dimensions (and it doesn't know which are most important to you). Yes, `fmincon` uses double precision by default just like the rest of Matlab.